# How can I install Python in IIS 7.5

Tags: windows, python, iis-7.5

I want to install python 3.2 in my IIS7.5 server so that I can use something like this :

http://localhost/index.py

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Microsoft instructions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494).

In a nutshell though, you give execution privileges to the IIS directory that holds the files, and then set up the python.exe file as the default handler for .py files. It's pretty much the same as other CGI stuff in IIS.